# Error opening transformations in Pentaho DI in Mac

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I have installed Pentaho DI and it works for me but not always.

Pentaho DI lets me open only 3 transformations and when I try to open one more (in the menu) the window does not appear.

Also when I push a button who opens a dialog box it appears me an error like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.panel_shouldShowFilename(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.dialogProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSSavePanel.setAccessoryView(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.open(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.job.entries.shell.JobEntryShellDialog$12.widgetSelected(JobEntryShellDialog.java:690)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.job.entries.shell.JobEntryShellDialog.open(JobEntryShellDialog.java:714)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonJobDelegate.editJobEntry(SpoonJobDelegate.java:259)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editJobEntry(Spoon.java:8564)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.job.JobGraph.editEntry(JobGraph.java:2836)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.job.JobGraph.mouseDoubleClick(JobGraph.java:633)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1339)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7939)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9214)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:653)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

I don't know what can be. Java version maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version? Pentaho 6.0.0 didnt work on the mac. 6.0.1 fixes it

Answer (score 0):

From the stack-trace I see that it is happens when you double-click on JobEntry step in your transformation:

```
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editJobEntry(Spoon.java:8564)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.job.JobGraph.editEntry(JobGraph.java:2836)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.job.JobGraph.mouseDoubleClick(JobGraph.java:633)
```

It is attempts to open file dialog in response to this action:

```
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog.open(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.job.entries.shell.JobEntryShellDialog$12.widgetSelected(JobEntryShellDialog.java:690
```

And then NPE is thrown. So it is not a java version. Very likely you are not use repository to store transformation/jobs, or use it but some of items in repository may still have links to filesystem, or any other.

That is might be a case when different transformation is reference same file, or one transformation opened from repository, other from filesystem, having same name but trying to reference one job entry.

Nobody knows better than you with you unique environment. If you can reproduce this NPE with job/transformation example I would suggest to open bug in [jira.pentaho.org](http://jira.pentaho.org) for '[Data Integration](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI)' project.